# Serve static files from another server while keeping the process invisible

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, amazon-s3

What I am trying to achieve is to serve files from an S3 bucket for multiple websites without showing the real path of the items. The files are stored in the S3 bucket like: bucket/website

Example:

```
domain: domain.com
static: static.domain.com
```

I do not want to create S3 buckets for every website, so I want to store all the files in a bucket folder and serve them from there with a script.

I currently got:

```
<?php

    $path = "domain";
    $file = "filename";

    // Save a copy of the file
    file_put_contents($file, fopen($path . $file, 'r'));

    // Set the content type and output the contents
    header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($file));
    readfile($file);

    // Delete the file
    unlink($file);

?>
```

but it's not that clean since I save the file and then output it. Saving the file could potentially cause a mess due to the fact that the websites might have files with the same name.
I'm also lacking the .htaccess file to make the proper rewrites so it would appear that you got the file from static.domain.com/file and not a static.domain.com/script.

Any suggestions on how to realize this would be great! Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Handling static files via PHP, moreover by saving a copy locally, is super inefficient; you'd be better off just serving them from the web server directly. Ultimately, the web server really needs to handle this, don't drag PHP into it. That means your web server needs to be able to act as proxy; whether this is possible on a limited shared host is questionable. An alternative might be a CDN.

Comment: It is not a shared hosting, it's a vps. Currently I have a S3 bucket for every website, but in this rythm I will hit the 100 bucket limit on AWS so I'm interested in keeping all the files in only one bucket.

Comment: So you have full access to configure Apache(?) however you like? What's the issue with the .htaccess file then?

Comment: Yes, full Apache config is available, the issue is that the files are not local, and I would like to hide the fact that the files are coming from one bucket instead of the website static domain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configure Apache to [*proxy* the request](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) to S3. Something like:

```
RewriteRule /path/to/static/files/(.*) http://my.bucket.s3.amazon.com/$1 [P]
```

This means a request to your web server for `/path/to/static/files/foo.jpg` will cause your web server to fetch the file from `my.bucket.s3.amazon.com/foo.jpg` and serve it as if it came from your web server directly.

However, note that this somewhat negates the point of S3 for the purposes of offloading traffic. It just offloads the storage, which is fine, but your web server still needs to handle every single request, and in fact has some overhead in terms of bandwidth due to having to fetch it from another server. You should at the very least look into [caching a copy on-server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_cache.html), and/or using a CDN in front of all this.

Comment: I am using CloudFlare as CDN.